# Can't Create Configurable Products with multiple Attributes programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, programmatically

I'm trying to create a configure product with multiple attributes.
Here is my code.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    try {
        $simpleProduct
        //    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
            ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
            ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
        //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
            ->setSku('simple99y'.time()) //SKU
            ->setName('test simple product99') //product name
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
            ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
            ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
            ->setColor(24)
            ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
            ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
            ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
            ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
            ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
            ->setDescription('This is a long description')
            ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
            ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
            ->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                    'qty' => 999 //qty
                )
            )
            ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
        $simpleProduct->save();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        error_log( print_r($e->getMessage(),true) );
    }

    $simpleProduct2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    try {
        $simpleProduct2
        //    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
            ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
            ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
        //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
            ->setSku('simple98w'.time()) //SKU
            ->setName('test simple product98') //product name
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
            ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
            ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
            ->setColor(25)
            ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
            ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
            ->setPrice(22.22) //price in form 11.22
            ->setCost(33.33) //price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
            ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
            ->setDescription('This is a long description')
            ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
            ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
            ->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                    'qty' => 999 //qty
                )
            )
            ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
        $simpleProduct2->save();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        error_log( print_r($e->getMessage(),true) );
    }

    $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    try {
    $configProduct
    //    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
            ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
            ->setTypeId('configurable') //product type
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
    //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
            ->setSku('configurable96'.time()) //SKU
            ->setName('test config product96') //product name
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
            ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
            ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
            ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
            ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
            ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
            ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
            ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
            ->setDescription('This is a long description')
            ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
            ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
            ->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                )
            )
            ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)) //assign product to categories
        ;
        /**/
        /** assigning associated product to configurable */
        /**/
        $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(92, 211)); //attribute ID of attribute 'color' and 'Banda' in my store

        $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
        error_log("config attributes: " . print_r($configurableAttributesData, true));
        $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
        $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

        $configurableProductsData = array();
        $configurableProductsData[$simpleProduct->getId()] = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
            '0' => array(
                'label' => 'Green', //attribute label
                'attribute_id' => '92', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                'value_index' => '24', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
                'pricing_value' => '21' //value for the pricing
             ),
            '1' => array(
                'label' => 'Johny', //attribute label
                'attribute_id' => '211', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                'value_index' => '238', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
                'pricing_value' => '4' //value for the pricing
            )
        );


        $configurableProductsData[$simpleProduct2->getId()] = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
            '0' => array(
                'label' => 'Grey', //attribute label
                'attribute_id' => '92', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                'value_index' => '25', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
                'pricing_value' => '25' //value for the pricing
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'label' => 'Johny', //attribute label
                'attribute_id' => '211', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                'value_index' => '238', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
                'pricing_value' => '4' //value for the pricing
            )
        );


        $configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
        $configProduct->save();
        ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

        $configProduct = null;
        $product_id = $message['product_id'];
        $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $configProduct->load( $product_id );

        //$stat = file_put_contents("/home/lalani/Desktop/logfile.log", json_encode($configProduct->getData()));

        error_log("success " . $stat);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        error_log( print_r($e->getMessage(),true) );
    }
```

and in the result I got this
[image]

This shouldn't be like this. There should be two options with Color and one with Banda. However, I have created an configurable product with single attribute but I am not getting success with two attributes. Please help me to figure out the problem.

**Updated**

Below link shows the admin side of 'Banda' attribute
[image]

Comment: Did you find what was wrong? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. The problem is `Banda` attribute didn't set to simple products(Apply to*). Solution, you need to set configurable and simple product also.
So, You've to check once again `Banda` attribute.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't get your point. can u tell me that where should i change the code. because I'm following this link 

http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-product/

can u give me the solution via relating it with this example ??

Comment: you've to change back-end only not code admin->catalog->manage attributes->edit `banda` attribute -> set apply to simple products

Comment: I've updated my question with snapshot of "admin-side of 'Banda' attribute".....Please check and guide me further please

Comment: Check once again `color` attribute if you create that attribute. The problem is, configurable product creates many simple product which is apply by attributes, That's why products are not showing down in associated products section. then, Re-index all in index management and clear cache.. that's it.

Comment: And you can check once comments of `http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-product/` tutorial.